# Crear una columna a partir de datos de otra columna

Tags: powerbi, datos, dax

buenos dias.

Tengo 2 columnas en una tabla de power bi donde tengo que identificar si una columna cumple con los datos de otra columna. En el caso sea verdadero seria un paquete completo, caso contrario no.

Deberia usar un IF o SWITCH o alguna otra formula?
Alguna recomendacion?

[image: Ejemplo: una cuenta debe contener la moneda 80,2 y 98. De ser asi seria una cuenta completa, caso contario no.]

Answer (score 0):

Tienes dos formas de hacerlo, en el mismo Power BI, añadiendo una columna calculada o bien hacerlo en el paso de Power Query. La forma recomendada es la última.

Para ello, debes ir a "Transformar datos", identificar y seleccionar la tabla en la que tienes estas columnas. Luego en el menú superiro eliges "Agregar Columna" --> "Columna Condicional".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pones un nombre a la columna nueva y configuras la condición:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En micaso (yo no tengo tus columnas) comparo la columna RECID con la ID_Cli, si coinciden le pongo "Paquete completo" y en caso contrario "No".

Debes fijarte que por defecto donde pone "Valor" espera una valor escrito, pero tienes a la izquierda un desplegable para "Seleccionar una columna" .

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Deberá aparecerte la columna nueva, le das a "Cerrar y aplicar" en el menú "Inicio" y se te cargará a Power BI.